# excel vba for each loop takes 2 steps at once

Tags: excel, for-loop, foreach, vba

I want to process every element of a for-loop. Taking this code, why is just every second element processed?

```
For Each row In ws.Rows
    If IsEmpty(row.Cells(row.row, 1)) Then
        Exit For
    Else
        MsgBox row.Cells(row.row, 1).value
    End If
Next
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: It's been a while since I've used VBA, but shouldn't you be looking at ws.Cells(row.row, 1) instead of row.Cells(row.row, 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of refering to Row.Cells refer to Worksheet.Cells.
Also, you might want to select the ActiveRange of the worksheet, that should prevent a lot of useless Rows in your for-each.

Check out MSDN for examples on this.

Answer (score 0):

Setting ws to a Range with the range of cells B1:B10 which contain the values 1-10 respectively will produce the desired result:

Sub Macro1()
Dim ws As Range

Set ws = Range("B1:B10")

For Each Row In ws.Rows

```
If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(Row.Row, 1)) Then
    Exit For
Else
    MsgBox ws.Cells(Row.Row, 1).Value
End If
```

Next

End Sub